# Will the login functionality built into the Users API stop working on April 20th?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-openid

I am currently using the Users API ([this one here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/users/)) with the Go language on my Google App Engine application.  My users are getting the warning message when they first grant permissions that says "OpenID 2.0 for Google accounts is going away. Developers should migrate to OpenID Connect by April 20, 2015."  But I can't find any warnings in the documentation for the Users API anywhere saying that anything will stop working, like I do all throughout other sections regarding OpenID 2.0 ([here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID2)).

I am using very little of the Users API code, just to create the login urls like this:

```
url, _ := user.LoginURLFederated(c, return_url, "www.google.com/accounts/o8/id")
```

And to read the users' email addresses, like this:

```
u := user.Current(appengine.NewContext(r))
email := u.Email
```

Do I need to worry about migrating, or will the Users API handle everything without failing after April 20th?

Comment: I was wondering the same. It would be very strange/broken if google's user service was still using oauth1. Maybe only happens to users that first accessed the appspot back when oauth1 was used? If so it would be interesting to know what happens to those after the deadline. I guess they will be offered to signin again.

Comment: Old users do not see the message when their sign in cookie expires and all they have to do is sign in to their Google account again.  They will get it only if/when they have to re-authorize, which I don't think they have to do unless they explicitly unauthorize my app.  I have done this with my own account just to test this out.

Comment: Yes but its not possible to test this until it deprecates. Hope a googler steps in here.

Comment: That is my hope!  I am getting a little desperate here, I don't want to have to redevelop my entire sign in process just in case, but I just might have to if I don't hear from somebody soon.

Comment: Its impossible that user service is broken like that but it might force users to log-in again and that can break things.

Comment: Impossible?  And why would cause problems if my users had to sign in again?

Comment: By impossible i mean google would have informed that userservice wont work. It would be a huge issue if it did stop working. None of the docs say anything.

Comment: I believe the warning is related to what you do before calling user.Current (LoginFederated is not OAuth 2.0). Please see these links: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID2?_ga=1.153281464.1089820907.1403527918 and https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#openid-connect

Comment: I had found those links before I posted my question.  What I am not clear about is: does the User service use old OAuth?  And if so, will it stop working on the 20th, or will Google update their code in time?  Since their are no warnings on the User service documentation, that would lead me to think that I'm ok... it's just a little scary not knowing for sure.

Comment: The call user.LoginURLFederated is definitely OpenID. So yes, the way you're using Users is affected by the deprecation and you could expect it to stop working. If you migrate to OAuth 2.0 authentication with Users, your users won't receive the warnings and you'll be safe about the deprecation deadline.

Comment: @Mario, since the only thing I'm really trying to access is the user.Email, is there really any difference between me using user.LoginURLFederated() vs user.LoginURL()?

Comment: I was away for a few days but as Glenn answered, yes, there is a difference and indeed is the point of conflict of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it turns out that the answer is "YES!".  Definitely stopped working.  The older development versions of my website now take you to an error page when you try to sign in.  Luckily I had moved away from the User package before the deadline to the [much](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29783824/what-is-actually-the-preferred-javascript-method-to-let-my-users-sign-in-with-go) [buggier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755539/error-when-loading-google-oauth2-javascript-api-while-logged-into-multiple-googl) [Google Sign-In for Websites](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in).

Comment: You say "no", but to what? It sounds like your answer to your original question is actually "yes, it will (did) stop working".

Answer (score 6):

Please read this information:
    https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenID2Migration
    https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect
    https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/auth-migration

You may also find this [forum post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-go/s_lv0tJCAyE) helpful.

Apps that use `user.LoginURLFederated` in conjunction with Google Accounts will stop working.  These apps need to follow the information in the first link above to migrate.

Apps can continue to use `user.LoginURLFederated` for use with various other third-party OpenID2 service providers.