# Migrating OpenID to OAuth2.0 in Google AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-openid, google-account

As of April 20th with the deprecation of certain google APIs, our Google Appengine app has stopped working.

Going from:
https://svusdnewstudent.appspot.com/login

To:
https://svusdnewstudent.appspot.com/_ah/login_redir?claimid=https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id&continue=https://svusdnewstudent.appspot.com/main

I get an Error: Server Error 500. There are no errors listed in the logs in the developer console. I believe it is using the wrong API and I don't know how to migrate it. I've tried searching all the migration tutorials but they don't make sense to me or don't seem to apply to this particular situation. I'm not a web developer, I'm a network specialist, so I'm iffy on these things. The guy who would do this stuff normally isn't around anymore.

I have access to all the python files, I know how to download, change and publish the app itself, but I believe this is something that needs to be sorted in the developer console, though I could be wrong.

Comment: It's funny how companies don't change this in advance. Now regarding the issue itself, this question is too broad. I suggest hiring a programmer if you guys don't have the expertise or posting the specific piece of code that pertains to the URL call in question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make this work, you will need to read through Google's documentation on how to migrate, [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/auth-migration#oid2).

They suggest using their JavaScript API, [Google Sign-In for Websites](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in).  I have done this on my website, but have run into several issues with a simple implementation, see my questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29783824/what-is-actually-the-preferred-javascript-method-to-let-my-users-sign-in-with-go) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755539/error-when-loading-google-oauth2-javascript-api-while-logged-into-multiple-googl) for more info.

I hope this helps.